# Python logging BufferingSMTPHandler outputs to console as well after multiple log entries

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

Basically what I want is to figure out why after a certain number of entries, instead of sending the logs to the handler only, it is also displaying them in terminal window.. and what I can do to stop that... not needed but a plus, would be why it is sending 4 copies of same log e-mails.
it is generating almost all of the log entries within 1-2 seconds

Having an issue in Python 2.7.13 with Logging module, I've used some examples I found here as well as the example of buffering SMTP handler from Vinay that he included in the logging module so that I could get TLS support into it. I'm having 2 Issues, the 1st is one that I am not very pleased about... I am performing logging inside an app I wrote that automates connection to BMC/LOM on servers within multiple data centers nationwide, it gathers information on multiple owner groups, from multiple sources of truth, handles connecting to correct bastion/jumphost combinations (currently, I am also working on building my own servers to streamline it all), and handles multiple different credential combinations that are based on of group ownership, manufacture... so on and so forth, it displays details on the asset to the technicians, asset tags, serial, manufacturer, model, config code, group ownership, IP's MAC's VLANs, parent chassis if the unit is a node/blade.. currently I want to run logging in debug mode, while I hammer out all the bugs while I work on the GUI (building that with Tkinter). I wanted to give a little background on what the app does before I get into the issues... issue 1, when I query and thusly connect to hosts from one group, I've no issues at all, I get a log e-mail with 55(roughly) log entries showing me who was using the app, what they queried for, and the results they got... works great (except for one minor issue which is the 2nd problem). Then on another groups host, I get multiple log entries flooding out into console, usually it seems to happen when I get around 65 entries in the log, it starts dumping to console as well, it still emails out the logs, but I do not want them dumping to console... not to mention I've got multiple other tasks that the user can call, that generate a good deal more info and debug logs if I need them (and currently since it is running at debug level is an issue for me)..  problem number 2, when the buffering SMTP handler sends the logs out, I get 4 copies of the same e-mail, I can not find any explanation for this.. I have another version of this that operates on a separate thread when it sends the logging emails, I have tried the capacity at 250 (should be more than enough for this iteration) 500, 750, 1500... it always seems that once I hit 65 entries, it starts to push them to console as well.

```
class log_handle(logging.handlers.BufferingHandler):
        def __init__(self, (mailhost, port), fromaddr, toaddrs, subject, capacity):
                logging.handlers.BufferingHandler.__init__(self, capacity)
                self.mailhost = mailhost
                self.mailport = None
                self.fromaddr = fromaddr
                self.toaddrs = toaddrs
                self.subject = subject
                self.username = lg1a
                self.password = lg2a

        def flush(self):
                if len(self.buffer) > 0:
                        try:
                                import smtplib
                                import string
                                try:
                                        from email.utils import formatdate
                                except ImportError:
                                        formatdate = self.date_time
                                port = self.mailport
                                if not port:
                                        port = smtplib.SMTP_PORT
                                smtp = smtplib.SMTP(self.mailhost, port)
                                msg = "From: %s\r\nTo: %s\r\nSubject: %s\r\n\r\n" % (self.fromaddr, string.join(self.toaddrs, ","), self.subject)
                                if self.username:
                                        smtp.ehlo()
                                        smtp.starttls()
                                        smtp.ehlo()
                                        smtp.login(self.username, self.password)
                                for record in self.buffer:
                                        s = self.format(record)
                                        msg = msg + s + "\r\n"
                                smtp.sendmail(self.fromaddr, self.toaddrs, msg)
                                smtp.quit()
                        except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
                                self.handleError(record)

logger = logging.getLogger('redacted: ' +basever+ ' CLI')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('Logged by: ' +user+ ' @ %(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s ::::  %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
mail_handle = log_handle(("redacted", redacted), "redacted", ['redacted'], 'redacted error logging USER: ' +user, 1500)
mail_handle.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
mail_handle.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(mail_handle)
atexit.register(logging.shutdown)
```

example of logs I'm getting

> Logged by: Matt @ 07/31/2017 14:41 - redacted Version: 2.2.0a CLI - INFO ::::  Searching via hosname
>
> Logged by: Matt @ 07/31/2017 14:41 - redacted Version: 2.2.0a CLI - DEBUG ::::  redacted - q=host=redacted - {'val_eq': 'redacted', 'tag_eq': 'host.name'}
>
> Logged by: Matt @ 07/31/2017 14:41 - redacted Version: 2.2.0a CLI - INFO ::::  Setting up redacted API
>
> Logged by: Matt @ 07/31/2017 14:41 - redacted Version: 2.2.0a CLI - DEBUG :::: redacted
>
> Logged by: Matt @ 07/31/2017 14:41 - redacted Version: 2.2.0a CLI - INFO ::::  Calling redacted API
>
> Logged by: Matt @ 07/31/2017 14:41 - redacted Version: 2.2.0a CLI - DEBUG ::::  Storing the data
>
> Logged by: Matt @ 07/31/2017 14:41 - redacted Version: 2.2.0a CLI - INFO ::::  Host is redacted
>
> Logged by: Matt @ 07/31/2017 14:41 - redacted Version: 2.2.0a CLI - DEBUG ::::  redacted
>
> Logged by: Matt @ 07/31/2017 14:41 - redacted Version: 2.2.0a CLI - INFO ::::  regex searches have been compiled
>
> Logged by: Matt @ 07/31/2017 14:41 - redacted Version: 2.2.0a CLI - INFO ::::  OOB IP is found
>
> Logged by: Matt @ 07/31/2017 14:41 - redacted Version: 2.2.0a CLI - DEBUG ::::  OOB IP is
>
> Logged by: Matt @ 07/31/2017 14:41 - redacted Version: 2.2.0a CLI - INFO 
>   ::::  OOB MAC is found
>
> Logged by: Matt @ 07/31/2017 14:41 - redacted Version: 2.2.0a CLI - DEBUG ::::  OOB MAC is redacted
>
> Logged by: Matt @ 07/31/2017 14:41 - redacted Version: 2.2.0a CLI - INFO ::::  Eth0 IP is found
>
> Logged by: Matt @ 07/31/2017 14:41 - redacted Version: 2.2.0a CLI - DEBUG ::::  Eth0 IP is redacted
>
> Logged by: Matt @ 07/31/2017 14:41 - redacted Version: 2.2.0a CLI - INFO ::::  Eth0 MAC is found
>
> Logged by: Matt @ 07/31/2017 14:41 - redacted Version: 2.2.0a CLI - DEBUG ::::  Eth0 MAC is redacted

(I've never posted here before so If I've got something wrong feel free to let me know)

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Can you boil down (or organize) the info in the top paragraph to make it easier for someone to get the gist of what you're after in a sentence or two?

Comment: Basically what I want is to figure out why after a certain number of entries, instead of sending the logs to the handler only, it is also displaying them in terminal window.. and what I can do to stop that... not needed but a plus, would be why it is sending 4 copies of same log e-mails.

Comment: so 2 things, after going home for the night, i found a few lines where I goofed and used logging.info and logging.debug instead of logger.... so the dumps to console seem to happen directly after this point... once fixed they seem to have gone away.... the other way I was able to temporarily solve it prior to finding my mistake, which actually pointed out my mistake to me.. was to actually call the root logger and point it at my handler...